# How do I select all Individuals with the same Type in Protege?

Tags: sparql, protege

I have an ontology in Protege based on two facts: 1. Car is a vehicle. 2. Bike is a vehicle. Both Individuals CAR and BIKE are type of VEHICLE. How do select them with SPARQL-query as Individuals with the same Type? [image: here's the screen]

Comment: just use two variables with the same predicate and object in the triple pattern. Like `select ?s1 ?s2 where  {?s1 <p> <o> . ?s2 <p> <o> . filter(?s1 != ?s2)}` - for the future, you should show the SPARQL queries that you tried so far. This is not a "request for query platform" - it makes sense to have a look at an RDF and SPARQL tutorial, especially since your question is rather a basic SPARQL query. And I'm pretty sure you would have been able to find the query by yourself when just having a basic SPARQL understanding

Comment: Do you mean I have to replace <p> <o> with predicate TYPE and object VEHICLE? but I need to find all Subjects that happens to be in triples with the same Predicate and Object.. e.g. it't not me who specifies in query Predicate and Object.